# FOR and WHile loop is working in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Strangely FOR and While loop not working in my controller function.

```
function information(Request $request){
    $exp=0;
    while($exp=0){
        echo 'While loop<br>';
        $exp++;
    }
    for($exp=0; $exp > 5; $exp++){
        echo 'For loop<br>';
    } 
}
```

Everything seems fine in loop. Not getting what causing it.

Comment: change `=` to `==` ` assignment` and `equal to` are different things more on : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: @Pradeep Ok while loop got syntax error. Thanks. Can you tell something about FOR loop. FOR loop is the one I was trying to do to insert multiple record. But when it failed I decided to switch to WHILE.

Comment: Well you check for `$exp > 5` which is invalid from beginning on because you initialize $exp with 0. So you probably want `$exp < 5`to run it 5 times

Comment: `$exp > 5` in for loop your condition is not matching since $exp is never gona greater than 5 as it 0

Comment: @Pradeep you should sum up everything and post the correct answer :)

Comment: @frnak ohh damn... I don't believe I made that stupid mistake.... I am so sorry about that silly question :(

Comment: no worries - always happy to have something more straight forward to answer :D

Comment: it happens don't worry happy coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code

```
    function information(Request $request){
        $exp=0;
        // = to ==
        while($exp==0){
            echo 'While loop<br>';
            $exp++;
        }

        // change $exp greater than 5 then it works
        for($exp=10; $exp > 5; $exp--){
            echo 'For loop<br>';
        } 
    }
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: beware! this requires $exp-- if you set it to 10, otherwise this will run infinitly